# How to get Claims Principal in Azure Function running Node?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, claims-based-identity, principal

I found an [example](https://medium.com/medialesson/role-based-authorization-in-azure-functions-with-azure-ad-and-app-roles-b1fed5714c91) of getting Claims Principal in C# Azure Function:

```cs
public static class SampleFunction
{
    [FunctionName("Sample")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "sample")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, 
        ClaimsPrincipal principal) // <=here
    {
        var roles = principal.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "roles").Select(e => e.Value);
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I get the same principal in a NodeJS Azure Function?